# Python Edit/Rename Key Names in .json

Tags: python, json, key, rename

Is there a way to change the Key name? 
I need to change the name `"Class123"` like it is in the Example. I can change the Value but I don't know how to change the key name.

Example .json :

```
{
    "Class123": "classvalue", 
    "name1": {
        "name2": {
            "name3": {
                "Y": 158.8, 
                "X": 201.46
            }, 
            "name4": {
                "Y": 159.68, 
                "X": 200.32
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Starting like this:

```
with open('my.json') as json1:
    data = json.load(json1)
    for item in data:
```

Comment: Your data is a dictionary. `help(dict)`. Then maybe dump the JSON back.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no way to "change" a key name.
The best you can do is to copy the value to another key by using `pop`:

```
d = {'old_name': 1}
d['new_name'] = d.pop('old_name')
print(d)
# {'new_name': 1}
```

Comment: d['new_name'] = d.pop('old_name') Thank you so much it worked

Comment: Thanks! this helped.

Comment: seems strange :)

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to add my method here since it expands the singular naming to using a dict of keys.

Lets say you have a sample JSON list `ga_list` and you would like to change all the names with a dict key `names_key` :

```
names_key = { 'ga:date'            : 'date' ,
              'ga:bounceRate'      : 'bounce' ,
              'ga:newUsers'        : 'new_users', 
              'ga:pageviews'       : 'page_views',
              'ga:sessions'        : 'sessions',
              'ga:uniquePageviews' : 'unique_page_views',
              'ga:users'           : 'users'
              }

ga_list = [{
      'ga:bounceRate': 34.478408,
      'ga:date': '20151203',
      'ga:newUsers': 1679,
      'ga:pageviews': 550,
      'ga:sessions': 307,
      'ga:uniquePageviews': 467,
      'ga:users': 256},
    {'ga:bounceRate': 21.28534,
      'ga:date': '20151204',
      'ga:newUsers': 164,
      'ga:pageviews': 594,
      'ga:sessions': 305,
      'ga:uniquePageviews': 476,
      'ga:users': 252},
    {'ga:bounceRate': 13.8372346,
      'ga:date': '20151205',
      'ga:newUsers': 152,
      'ga:pageviews': 826,
      'ga:sessions': 330,
      'ga:uniquePageviews': 241,
      'ga:users': 200}]

for row in ga_list:
  for k, v in names_key.items():
    for old_name in row:
      if k == old_name:
        row[v] = row.pop(old_name)

print(ga_list)

>>>
[{'bounce': 34.47842608,
  'date': '20151203',
  'new_users': 1679,
  'page_views': 550,
  'sessions': 307,
  'unique_page_views': 467,
  'users': 256},
 {'bounce': 21.28534,
  'date': '20151204',
  'new_users': 164,
  'page_views': 594,
  ....
  'unique_page_views': 241,
  'users': 200}]
```

And there you have it all the old names are renamed according to the key.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: FYI RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
your_dict[new_key] = your_dict.pop(old_key)
```

Removing the old key from your dict and creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do it is with replace() function, but make sure that you have to convert your JSON Dict in to String first as Dictionary's key cannot be changed.

```
json_data = json_data.replace('key_old1','Key_new1').replace('key_old2','key_new2')
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers..!!

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this method because it also considers the substring & replaces it as well

Comment: This is very dangerous considering the text inside any field in the objects.