# Changing multiple keys on a JSON FILe using Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to update a new key into my JSON file if the conditions are met. The following is my python code attempting to make multiple updates in a JSON file.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 # Usage: update json file 
import json
import os

json_dir="/opt/rdm/adggeth/ADGG-ETH-02/20181008/"
json_dir_processed="/opt/rdm/adggeth/ADGG-ETH-02/20181008updated/"
for json_file in os.listdir(json_dir):
    if json_file.endswith(".json"):
        processed_json = "%s%s" % (json_dir_processed, json_file)
        json_file = json_dir + json_file
        print "Processing %s -> %s" % (json_file, processed_json)
        with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
            json_data = json.load(f)
            # replacement mapping
            update_map = {"grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile":"grp_farmerdts/hh_id",
                          "grp_farmerdts/hh_region":"grp_farmerdts/region",
                          "grp_farmerdts/hh_district":"grp_farmerdts/district",
                          "grp_farmerdts/hh_ward":"grp_farmerdts/ward",
                          "grp_farmerdts/hh_village":"grp_farmerdts/village"}

            diff_keys = update_map.keys() - json_data.keys()
            if not diff_keys:
                print("No Update to JSON keys")
            else:
                for k in diff_keys:
                    json_data[k] = json_data[update_map[k]]
        with open(processed_json, 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
    else:
        print "%s not a JSON file" % json_file
```

The JSON file i am trying to make update to is as follows:

```
{
    ....
    "farmerregistrd": "1", 
    "grp_farmerdts/region": "5", 
    "datacollid": "0923678275", 
    "_status": "submitted_via_web", 
    "enumtype": "2", 
    "deviceid": "352948096845916", 
    "start_time": "2019-04-03T10:57:23.620+03", 
    "_uuid": "f1069eae-33f8-4850-a549-49fcde27f077", 
    "grp_farmerdts/village": "2852", 
    "_submitted_by": null, 
    "formhub/uuid": "42cb3fc351a74fd89702078160f849ca", 
    "grp_farmerdts/hh_id": "623", 
    "grp_farmerdts/ward": "136", 
    ...
    "_userform_id": "adggeth_ADGG-ETH-REG02-20181008", 
    "_id": 711097, 
    "grp_farmerdts/district": "31"
}
```

My expected output from running the following python file is as follows

```
 {
        ....
        "farmerregistrd": "1", 
        "grp_farmerdts/hh_region": "5", 
        "datacollid": "0923678275", 
        "_status": "submitted_via_web", 
        "enumtype": "2", 
        "deviceid": "352948096845916", 
        "start_time": "2019-04-03T10:57:23.620+03", 
        "_uuid": "f1069eae-33f8-4850-a549-49fcde27f077", 
        "grp_farmerdts/hh_village": "2852", 
        "_submitted_by": null, 
        "formhub/uuid": "42cb3fc351a74fd89702078160f849ca", 
        "grp_farmerdts/hh_id": "623", 
        "grp_farmerdts/hh_ward": "136", 
        ...
        "_userform_id": "adggeth_ADGG-ETH-REG02-20181008", 
        "_id": 711097, 
        "grp_farmerdts/hh_district": "31"
    }
```

Comment: what's your problem/question?

Comment: Using my code i am unable to make my update my JSON file to fit the expected output as shown above.

Comment: Possible helper. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777924/python-edit-rename-key-names-in-json

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your expected output all particular keys need to be checked (not one of them). Change your logic as shown below:

```
...
json_data = json.load(f)
# replacement mapping
update_map = {"grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile":"grp_farmerdts/hh_id",
              "grp_farmerdts/hh_region":"grp_farmerdts/region",
              "grp_farmerdts/hh_district":"grp_farmerdts/district",
              "grp_farmerdts/hh_ward":"grp_farmerdts/ward", "grp_farmerdts/hh_village":"grp_farmerdts/village"}

diff_keys = update_map.keys() - json_data.keys()
if not diff_keys:
    print("No Update to JSON keys")
else:
    for k in diff_keys:
        if update_map[k] in json_data:
            json_data[k] = json_data[update_map[k]]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rdm/adggeth/ADGG-ETH-02/addfidkey.sh", line 40, in <module>
    diff_keys = update_map.keys() - json_data.keys()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'  #this is the error i am getting after running your code @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @MirieriMogaka. that means that you have used my code in wrong way. `json_data` and `update_map` are dictionaries. Use the proposed code attentively

Comment: @MirieriMogaka, what's your Python version?

Comment: I have copied my changes

Comment: python version 2.7.6

Comment: @MirieriMogaka, always add python version to your python questions

Comment: @MirieriMogaka, in your case - change the respective line to the following: `diff_keys = set(update_map.keys()) - set(json_data.keys())`

Comment: Noted i will be sure to include the version of python when posting my question

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rdm/adggeth/ADGG-ETH-02/addfidkey.sh", line 45, in <module>
    json_data[k] = json_data[update_map[k]]
KeyError: 'grp_farmerdts/region' # this is the error i am getting @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @MirieriMogaka, that means that your initial dict does not contain such key. That key was in your initial code as a replacement key. Check if that key is valid or consider another replacement key

Comment: This key "grp_farmerdts/region" is available in some of the JSON files not all i want to ignore if the key is not in a JSON file

Answer (score 2):

Using `re` module and `json.loads()` with `object_hook=` parameter ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.load)). This script will add `hh_` prefix to every `grp_farmerdts/*` key where isn't:

```
json_str = '''{
    "farmerregistrd": "1",
    "grp_farmerdts/region": "5",
    "datacollid": "0923678275",
    "_status": "submitted_via_web",
    "enumtype": "2",
    "deviceid": "352948096845916",
    "start_time": "2019-04-03T10:57:23.620+03",
    "_uuid": "f1069eae-33f8-4850-a549-49fcde27f077",
    "grp_farmerdts/village": "2852",
    "_submitted_by": null,
    "formhub/uuid": "42cb3fc351a74fd89702078160f849ca",
    "grp_farmerdts/hh_id": "623",
    "grp_farmerdts/ward": "136",
    "_userform_id": "adggeth_ADGG-ETH-REG02-20181008",
    "_id": 711097,
    "grp_farmerdts/district": "31"
}'''

import re
import json

def change_keys(d):
    return {re.sub(r'grp_farmerdts/((?!hh_)(\w+))', r'grp_farmerdts/hh_\1', k): v for k, v in d.items()}

print(json.dumps(json.loads(json_str, object_hook=change_keys), indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "farmerregistrd": "1",
    "grp_farmerdts/hh_region": "5",
    "datacollid": "0923678275",
    "_status": "submitted_via_web",
    "enumtype": "2",
    "deviceid": "352948096845916",
    "start_time": "2019-04-03T10:57:23.620+03",
    "_uuid": "f1069eae-33f8-4850-a549-49fcde27f077",
    "grp_farmerdts/hh_village": "2852",
    "_submitted_by": null,
    "formhub/uuid": "42cb3fc351a74fd89702078160f849ca",
    "grp_farmerdts/hh_id": "623",
    "grp_farmerdts/hh_ward": "136",
    "_userform_id": "adggeth_ADGG-ETH-REG02-20181008",
    "_id": 711097,
    "grp_farmerdts/hh_district": "31"
}
```

Comment: How can apply this for several JSON files in a folder

Comment: @MirieriMogaka Use `json.load(<file object>, object_hook=change_keys)` to parse json and change the keys. Them you can save the object with `file.write` and `json.dumps`, or simply `json.dump(<file object)`