# JSON rename nested dictionary name

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Im trying to edit the nested dictionary name
i want to run in for loop this json file to create it 5 times in different name

```
{
  "fruits": {
      "color": "green",
      "fruit": "apple",
  }
}
```

How can i change the **fruits** **to fruits1, fruits2, fruits3 .... etc.**
I dont want to change the inside of the dictionary only the main name (fruits every time on foor loop)

```
filename = "test.json"

for i in range(1,5+1):
    with open(filename, 'r') as params:
         data = json.load(params, object_pairs_hook=OrederedDict)

    for key in data.items()
        print(key[0]) # its print fruits
        key[0] = "fruits"+str(i)

    with open(filename, 'w') as json_file:
         json.dump(data,json_file)
```

Example (after):

```
{
  "fruits1": {
      "color": "green",
      "fruit": "apple",
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't edit JSON, you read/parse it into an internal structure (at that point it's not JSON any more!), modify that structure and then write it again. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Edit/Rename Key Names in .json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777924/python-edit-rename-key-names-in-json)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt so how can i edit the main name (fruits) every time?

Comment: Do you really need to generate the files or do you simply need to change the dictionary in Python (as suggested by Ulrich)? If it's the former, are you limited to use Python for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the name of a key in a Python dictionary. What you can do is choose another name for an existing key, assign the original key's value to that then delete (*del*) the original key.

Given your sample data, you could do this:

```
D = {
  "fruits": {
      "color": "green",
      "fruit": "apple",
  }
}

D['fruits1'] = D['fruits']
del D['fruits']
print(D)
```

Comment: its on JSON file not dictionary on python
d= ??
{
   'fruits': {
    }
}

Comment: Quote from your original question "Im [sic] trying to edit the nested dictionary"

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.pop()`

with sample data you gives to us, you could do this:

```
a = {
  "fruits": {
      "color": "green",
      "fruit": "apple",
  }
}

a['fruits1'] = a.pop('fruits')
print(a)
```