# How do I replace the key in a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Could you please tell me how can I replace the `key` in a `JSON file`?

JSON file structure:

```
[
   {
      "id" : "365",
      "credits" : [ {
        "login" : "user1",
        "password" : "pa$$w0rd"
      } ]
    }, {
      "id" : "366",
      "credits" : [ {
        "Login" : "user2",
        "password" : "pa$$w0rd"
      } ]
    }
]
```

it is necessary that the `login` key be of the same type, i.e. with one `register` throughout the document, all `Login` keys become `login`.

This is necessary for further analysis and downloading of information from the `JSON file`.

```
with open ("test.json", "r") as read_file_json:
    data_json = json.load(read_file_json)
    for n in range(len(data_json)):
        id = (data_json[n]['id'])
        id = str(id)
        for credits in data_json[n]["credits"]:
            login = credits["login"]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please give a try  in the last line `credits[newKey]=credits.pop(old_key)`

Comment: If you *only* want to replace `Login` with `login`, loading the json file as a string and using `str.replace()` would be the simplest solution. Unless you've got a user named `Login`. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Edit/Rename Key Names in .json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777924/python-edit-rename-key-names-in-json)

Comment: question flagged as duplicate of :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777924/python-edit-rename-key-names-in-json/49777985        . Try to have a look at json_data.replace()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to work with the *id* key. It serves no purpose. All you need is:

```
import json

with open ('test.json', encoding='utf-8') as read_file_json:
    js = json.load(read_file_json)
    for d in js:
        for c in d['credits']:
            if (v := c.get('Login', None)) is not None:
                c['login'] = v
                del c['Login']
    print(json.dumps(js, indent=2))
```