# Python: How to transform JSON file into an XML file and modify its keys

Tags: python, json, xml

I have an XML file like this:

```xml
<XML>
    <Report>
        <ReportNumber>178414417</ReportNumber>
        <ReportDatetime>2022-03-23T21:10:04</ReportDatetime>
        <Sender>Alexandra Bell</Sender>
        <Receiver>Tamara Watson</Receiver>
        <MessageToReceiver>Miss Watson, come here, I want to see you.</MessageToReceiver>
    </Report>
</XML>
```

and I would like to transform it into a JSON file which looks like this:

```json
{
 "report": {
  "report_number": 178414417,
  "report_datetime": "2022-03-23T21:10:04",
  "sender": "Alexandra Bell",
  "receiver": "Tamara Watson",
  "message_to_receiver": "Miss Watson, come here, I want to see you"
 }
}
```

I am able to carry out JSON to XML transformation using `json` and `xmlschema` (simple outline below) but what I'm not sure how to properly add that underscore to keys in JSON (e.g. XML file has element named `MessageToReceiver` and its corresponding key in JSON file should be named `message_to_receiver`).

```py
import xmlschema
import json

xsd_file = 'xsd_filename.xsd'
xml_file = 'xml_filename.xml'

xml_schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema(xsd_file)
xml_dict = xml_schema.to_dict(xml_file)
json_filename = 'json_filename.json' # Name for JSON file that will be created
with open(json_filename, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(xml_dict, outfile)
```

Comment: Dictionary keys cannot be edited, so add new keys and assign them values from old keys (pop) and remove old keys. - Similar question answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777924/python-edit-rename-key-names-in-json

Comment: @Pankaj Thank you for linking the other answer, I'll have a look. I was thinking maybe there is some way to map xpath for XML file to a list of keys that should be used in JSON.