# Is it possible to rename a json key name using its value in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested-json

I have this nested json dictionary and I want to rename the key name 'Keys' with its equivalent value using Python. I wonder if this is possible?

Current -  'Keys': ['AWS Backup']
I want it to be - 'AWS Backup': ['AWS Backup']

Sample json dictionary
{'TimePeriod': {'Start': '2022-11-28', 'End': '2022-11-29'}, 'Total': {}, 'Groups': [{'Keys': ['AWS Backup'], 'Metrics': {'UnblendedCost': {'Amount': '0.000000111', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['AWS Direct Connect'], 'Metrics': {'UnblendedCost': {'Amount': '0.0000111', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}, {'Keys': ['AWS Key Management Service'], 'Metrics': {'UnblendedCost': {'Amount': '0.000000111', 'Unit': 'USD'}}}

Tried do flatten the json but after doing it still no luck. I'm not sure if I can do it using pandas dataframe also? Plan to save that json also in a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best if you follow the same method as the answer here, you cannot rename it, but you can copy the data to a new key and get rid of the old one

```
d = {'old_name': 1}
d['new_name'] = d.pop('old_name')
```

[Python Edit/Rename Key Names in .json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777924/python-edit-rename-key-names-in-json)